# Ajax Commenting Tutorial? Ajax functionality works but appends 4 times. Why?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a curious situation with AJAX. My problem is that I'm trying to achieve commenting using AJAX and it works, but not quite. I'll explain.

I have this code for my AJAX commenting:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#new_comment').on('submit',function(event){
event.preventDefault();

var $form = $(event.currentTarget);

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: $form.attr('action'),
  dataType: 'json',
  data: $form.serialize(),
  success: function(response) {
    var $commentAuthor = $('<h4>').text(response.author);
    var $commentBody = $('<p>').text(response.body);
    var $comment = $('div').addClass('comment').append($commentAuthor,$commentBody);
    var $commentFeed = $('.comment-feed');
    $commentFeed.append(comment);
  },
  error: function() {
      alert('Something was wrong with your comment. Try again');
    }
  });
 });
});
```

This works fine in the sense that when I create a comment, my Terminal through rails s is telling me that the comment was created using JSON. Like so:

```
tarted POST "/posts/4/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-19 23:32:59 -0400
Processing by CommentsController#create as JSON
```

Its strange though because when I create a single comment, AJAX will somehow create 4 of them but the element inspector confirms that the web page only has one comment. If I make more comments its even worst. When I check my rails console, it also confirms that there is one comment in the database not 4. Lastly, when I refresh the page, the duplicates go away.

I was researching this on Stackoverflow and I've tried to insert this line of code.

```
 $('#new_comment').unbind('on').on('submit',function(event).......
```

But that didn't seem to work either. I'm not sure what the problem is but any help would be helpful. Thx.

-----------------EDIT--------------------

This is taken from my post show page:

```
<h1><%= @post.title %></h1>

<%= simple_format @post.body %>

<h3>Comments</h3>

<%= simple_form_for [@post, @comment] do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :author %>
 <%= f.input :body %>
 <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>

<div class="comment-feed">
 <% @post.comments.each do |post| %>
 <div class="comment">
  <h4><%= post.author %></h4>
  <p><%= post.body %></p>
 </div>
<% end %>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$("div")` isn't doing you any good. That expression selects all existing divs on the page and then adds the comment class, etc.

If you want to create a new element with jQuery, it ness to be passed in as an HTML fragment: `$("<div></div>")`

Comment: I've changed the $('div") to $('<div></div>') but it still didn't work. I still don't understand why it should make a difference. I've confirmed through the inspect element that only 1 div is being created. Yet four are showing up.

Comment: The only other suspicious part I can see from your example is `$commentFeed.append(comment)`. I assume you meant to put `$comment`, but if that's genuinely what you have in your code, does `comment` refer to something that could cause your issue?

Comment: That was a legit typo on my part, but still no luck. I don't know I guess I'll just sleep on it. I don't know why this is wrong. Thx for the help anyways Platinum.

Comment: Can you post your HTML? That will help.

Comment: Sure. And you know what, I think you're right with your first comment. I looked more closely and everytime I make a new comment, they're being appended to the previous one for the reasons you mentioned. Something is definitely up with one of my appends methods.